# Check Data for Last Quarter

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks

I have a dataframe in which the data is in the following format

```
process_date    ItemNo         ItemType
01-Mar-2019       1               abc
01-Jun-2019       2               cde
01-Sep-2019       1               abc
```

The data file is supplied every quarter with the above date format (Frist day of Quarter, instead of Last day).
The Requirement is to check if the File contains the data for the quarter it is supplied for, and one quartre before that.
So the File suplied in December (will contain data upto September 2019), and i need to verify if the data for September 2019 exists or not ? (the wrong file will only have data upto June-2019 -and processing should fail).

Another requirement on the same file (a separate requirement is to check the data for one previous Qtr, in this case check if June data exist in September file).

All needs to be done in Pyspark / Pandas dataframe.
Is there a way to check this. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Could you provide some code that you have tried?

Comment: Not sure, I couldn't figure out anything. All the solutions failed so no Luck ... :(

Comment: How is the File supplied in Dezember when you explicitly write "on the first day of quater" in my knowledge the first day of quater would be jannuary, april, july, october or not?

Comment: The file is for the quarter ( Mar, Jun, Sep, Dec). The file for Sep can be supplied at any time within the next 3 months so no fixed date for that. But the data will always have first day of Mar, Jun, Sep, Dec .. if that makes sense ?

Comment: Each quarter's file can be supplied at any time in the next 3 months (Mar file can come in Jun, Similarly Jun file can come In September etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find quarter and year for:

- Present day
- Last quarter
- Previous to last quarter

Check if record exists for quarter of that year:

```py
current_qtr = pd.Timestamp(datetime.datetime.now()).quarter
last_qtr = 4 if current_qtr - 1 == 0 else current_qtr - 1
prev_qtr = 4 if last_qtr - 1 == 0 else last_qtr - 1
current_year = datetime.datetime.now().year
last_qtr_yr = current_year - 1 if last_qtr == 4 else current_year
prev_qtr_yr = current_year - 1 if prev_qtr in [3, 4] else current_year
```

**Case: Both reports exist**

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=[["01-Mar-2022",1,"abc"],["01-Jun-2022",2,"cde"],["01-Sep-2022",1,"abc"]], schema=["process_date","ItemNo","ItemType"])
df = df.withColumn("process_date", F.to_date(df.process_date, "dd-MMM-yyyy"))
df = df.withColumn("quarter", F.quarter(df.process_date))
df = df.withColumn("year", F.year(df.process_date))

last_qtr_exists = bool(df.filter((F.col("quarter") == last_qtr) & (F.col("year") == last_qtr_yr)).collect())

prev_qtr_exists = bool(df.filter((F.col("quarter") == prev_qtr) & (F.col("year") == prev_qtr_yr)).collect())

[Out]:
+------------+------+--------+-------+----+
|process_date|ItemNo|ItemType|quarter|year|
+------------+------+--------+-------+----+
|  2022-03-01|     1|     abc|      1|2022|
|  2022-06-01|     2|     cde|      2|2022|
|  2022-09-01|     1|     abc|      3|2022|
+------------+------+--------+-------+----+

last_qtr_exists = True
prev_qtr_exists = True
```

**Case: Last quarter exists; but previous to last not***

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=[["01-Mar-2022",1,"abc"],["01-Jun-2022",2,"cde"]], schema=["process_date","ItemNo","ItemType"])
# repeat code from success case

[Out]:
+------------+------+--------+-------+----+
|process_date|ItemNo|ItemType|quarter|year|
+------------+------+--------+-------+----+
|  2022-03-01|     1|     abc|      1|2022|
|  2022-06-01|     2|     cde|      2|2022|
+------------+------+--------+-------+----+

last_qtr_exists = False
prev_qtr_exists = True
```

**Case: No report exists**

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=[["01-Mar-2022",1,"abc"],["01-Jun-2022",2,"cde"],["01-Sep-2022",1,"abc"]], schema=["process_date","ItemNo","ItemType"])
# repeat code from success case

[Out]:
+------------+------+--------+-------+----+
|process_date|ItemNo|ItemType|quarter|year|
+------------+------+--------+-------+----+
|  2019-03-01|     1|     abc|      1|2019|
|  2019-06-01|     2|     cde|      2|2019|
|  2019-09-01|     1|     abc|      3|2019|
+------------+------+--------+-------+----+

last_qtr_exists = False
prev_qtr_exists = False
```